# How to make addition symbol inside in a circle?

Tags: math-operators, circles

I need to make + and a dot representing multiplication in a circle.
How to do it?

Comment: Do you mean `$\bigodot$` and `$\bigoplus$`?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: @HarishKumar Oh yes!It works!

Comment: Please thank @HarishKumar by accepting his answer (and voting it up). That's better than thanks in a comment.

Comment: Also, as a reference take a look at [The Comprehensive LATEX Symbol List](http://www.tex.ac.uk/tex-archive/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf‎) !

Answer (score 66):

Probably you need this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
$\bigodot$ \quad $\bigoplus$ \quad $\bigotimes$
\end{document}
```

[image]

`amssymb` gives some variants:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}    
$\odot$ \quad $\oplus$ \quad $\otimes$ \quad $\ominus$ \quad $\oslash$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: If you're reading this, do you know how to invert the colors? Like, a white + sign in a black circle...

Comment: The drawback is that the "plus" or "minus" is in contact with the circle, which does not look always appropriate. For a small minus, there is `\circleddash` (U+229D ⊝).

Comment: Note that if you're writing equations, for instance using the *align* block, it's important to use odot, oplus, ominus and **not** the bigo versions, unless you want ugly looking equations.