# big dot operation with lower and upper bound in XeLatex

Tags: xetex

How can I write a big dot operation with lower and upper bound in XeLatex as represented in the figure? Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Arguably duplicate of [How to look up a symbol or identify a letter from a math alphabet or other character? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14/how-to-look-up-a-symbol-or-identify-a-letter-from-a-math-alphabet-or-other-chara)

Comment: Also [math operators - How to make addition symbol inside in a circle? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/137336/how-to-make-addition-symbol-inside-in-a-circle/137337#137337) & [math mode - Is there a \bigcdot symbol in LaTeX - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/125523/is-there-a-bigcdot-symbol-in-latex/125556#125556)

Comment: You're looking for `\bigodot` and `\substack`.  The latter is defined in `amsmath`.

Answer (score 1):

The command `\bigodot` by default is a "Variable-sized Math Operator", meaning it is larger in display mode than it is in inline mode. In addition, limits (if any) are placed above and below the symbol in display, but placed to the right (in super/subscript) position when inline. Thus the code

```
$\bigodot_{k=m+1}^M\mathbf{b}_{V^{(k)}}\quad
 \displaystyle{\bigodot_{k=m+1}^M\mathbf{b}_{V^{(k)}}}$
```

produces the following output:

[image]

If you don't like the space between `\bigodot` and `\mathbf{b}` you can enclose the lower limit in `\mathclap{...}`. This requires the `mathtools` package:

```
$\bigodot_{k=m+1}^M\mathbf{b}_{V^{(k)}}\quad
 \displaystyle{\bigodot_{\mathclap{k=m+1}}^M\mathbf{b}_{V^{(k)}}}$
```

Note that this also reduces space on the left.

[image]

To have two lines below the operator, use `\substack{j=1\\j\ne i}` for the lower limit. The `\substack` command requires the `amsmath` package, which is automatically loaded if you load `mathtools`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\[
\mathbf{b}_{V^{(i)}}\propto\bigodot_{\substack{j=1\\j\ne i}}^m\mathbf{f}_{V^{(j)}}\quad
\bigodot_{\mathclap{k=m+1}}^M\mathbf{b}_{V^{(k)}},\quad i=1:m
\]

\end{document}
```

As a last (very picky) comment, you may notice that the `j=1` and `j\ne i` aren't perfectly aligned in the `\substack`. This is because `1` and `i` don't have the same width. You can correct this by placing a `phantom` 1:

```
\substack{j=1\\j\ne\mathrlap{i}\phantom{1}}
```

[image]